# Unable to cast object XText to XElement

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm a bit stuck, currently getting a an error being caught in the exception 'ex' at the start of the second run through of the foreach loop.

Why is this happening and what am I doing wrong?

```
{"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XText' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'."}   System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}'
```

My code:

```
        public static void LoadMyThing()
    {
        string configfp = @"\ConfigFiles\config.xml";
        string basefp = @"\ConfigFiles\";
        try
        {
            List<string> xmlNodes = new List<string>();

            XDocument Xdoc = XDocument.Load(configfp);
            XElement XmlLst = Xdoc.Element("mylistener");

            foreach (XElement node in XmlLst.Element("parent").DescendantNodes())
            {
                thingy = (basefp + node.Value);
                Thingylist.Add(thing);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            WriteErrorLog("Thingy Loading error " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

The XML it's calling to:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mylistener>
  <config>
    <mailuser>b@c.com</mailuser>
    <mailpass>H</mailpass>
    <mailip>190</mailip>
    <mailport>2</mailport>
    <recipient>m</recipient>
  </config>
  <parent>
    <b>\RFC16</b>
    <b>\RFC122</b>
    <b>\RF1</b>
    <b>\RF32</b>
    <b>\R33</b>
    <b>\RFCIB</b>
  </parent>
</mylistener>
```

Comment: `DescendantNodes` returns nodes not elements. change `XElement` to  `XNode` or simply use `var`

Comment: XNode doesn't have attribute Value, how would I get the value out of the node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to be sure without seeing your XML, but if the `parent` node has non XElement descendants then I'd expect to see this. For example

```
<parent>
    <some node /> 
    some text
</parent>
```

You need to know how you want to handle this case, but one way to avoid an exception would be to iterate XNodes rather than XElements

```
foreach (XNode node in XmlLst.Element("parent").DescendantNodes())
{
    if (node is XElement)
    {
        thingy = (basefp + ((XElement)node).Value);
        Thingylist.Add(mibbler);
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added the XML and improved the code on the question so it makes more sense - XNode doesn't have a value property so not sure how I could get the value/inner text using that method.

Comment: You just need to cast the node as XElement. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately, seeing it in the try-catch there shouldn't be a need for an if function, that's what I have the try-catch for to write to an error log and alert me if something goes wrong whilst the service is running.

Comment: Instead of `DescendantNodes()` try using `Descendants()`; it returns only elements.